# Angular: Two inputs, one way mirroring

Tags: angular

Noob question here. I am on Angular 8. I have two text input fields. I would like to mirror the value of the first input to the second one, but if the value of the second input changes, the first input value should remain unchanged. This is what I've tried, but it doesn't seem to work...

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="first"><br>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="second" value="first">
<button (click)="show(first,second)">Click</button>
```

and my function

```
show(var1,var2){
    console.log(var1,var2);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you forgot [] on the second input

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="first"><br>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="second" [value]="first">
<button (click)="show(first,second)">Click</button>
```

here is the simple example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/simple-apollo-angular-example-pckhkf

Comment: Please can you check the stackblitz example I have updated it

Comment: Have you checked the value of the second input on the console log? I still get undefined...

Comment: @gothaf I have fixed, sorry I missed out the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a combination of two way binding and listening to the change of the first one:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="first" (ngModelChange)="second = $event"><br>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="second">
    <button (click)="show(first,second)">Click</button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent  {
  first: string;
  second: string;

  show(var1: string, var2: string){
    console.log(var1, var2);
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/simple-apollo-angular-example-nxcvpv?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: @gothaf ah yes, of course :) I've updated my answer. You don't need to (and shouldn't) bind to both `ngModel` and `value`. It can cause unwanted side effects. Better is to always just use one

Comment: Got it! Thank you!